# Sql query alternative way

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I want to find

Select no of employees joined with respect to year and month from employee table

My query is:

```
select to_char(JOINING_DATE,'YYYY') As "Year",
       to_char(JOINING_DATE,'MM') As "MOnth",
       Count(First_name) 
  from employee
 group by to_char(JOINING_DATE,'YYYY'),
          to_char(JOINING_DATE,'MM');
```

No error, runs successfully.

Is there any alternative way to get the same results as this query?

Comment: Alternative how, is it slow or something?

Comment: What's wrong with it? Why should you write the query in a different way?

Comment: Depending on your requirements, you can call the to_char function just once with mask `yyyy-mm`.

Comment: You should choose correct answers if they helped you. You're not giving people who answer your questions any credit at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

if you only group by year and month, you can do the following:

```
SELECT to_char(JOINING_DATE, 'MM-YYYY'), Count(First_name)
FROM test_date
GROUP BY to_char(JOINING_DATE, 'MM-YYYY')
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to order the results.  I would put the year and month into the same column:

```
Select to_char(JOINING_DATE, 'YYYY-MM') As YYYYMM", Count(*)
from employee
group by to_char(JOINING_DATE, 'YYYY-MM')
order by to_char(JOINING_DATE, 'YYYY-MM');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your query a bit and try:

```
SELECT YEAR(JOINING_DATE) As "Year", 
       MONTH(JOINING_DATE) As "Month",
       Count(First_name) 
FROM employee 
GROUP BY Year, Month;
```